# How to add a column to see whether they are match based on two lists of IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

[image: Data]

I have a dataframe in the left side (in orange) with the LeadOrderIDs. I want to add a column to the left to see whether the list of OrderId in the right (purple) is in the LeadOrder (Orange). Don't use the inner join...

How should I use python - Pandas to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post dataframes as text, not as images.  Also do you want *anywhere* in the left side, or in the same row on the left side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.isin` method. Here is an example how it would work. The data frame is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'LeadOrder':[1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,10], 'OrderId':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

The common elements are given by the following mask:

```
mask = df['LeadOrder'].isin(df['OrderId'])
```

And if you want to get the common elements just put this mask into the index place when subsetting the data frame:

```
df.loc[mask,]
```

In your case you will have to complete the OrderId column with `NA`s or some other irrelevant values that are not in the LeadOrder column for sure.